# How to change the \input paths from an initialization file (latexmkrc) to run latexpand and latexdiff on big projects?

Tags: texlive, latexmk, latexdiff

I am working on a project to compare, let's say, "Old/main.tex" and "New/main.tex" which are assumed to be two big LaTeX projects with multiple calls to \input{}. To do so, I am using latexpand on both files to create flattened versions "old.tex" and "new.tex", and then latexdiff to compare them. Both things can be achieved via a latexmkrc file with the following lines (by the way, latexdiff and latexpand are included in TeXLive so you can try this on Overleaf):

```
$pdflatex = "
latexpand New/main.tex > new.tex; 
latexpand Old/main.tex > old.tex;
latexdiff old.tex new.tex > main-d.tex;
pdflatex %O main-d.tex"
```

Yet, there is a problem: the issue of manually changing the \input paths on all files to include the New/ (Old/) folder structures when importing these main files from another project.

i.e. Suppose that the main.tex in "Old/main.tex" is actually imported from another project (along with its companion files) whose \input{}, \includegraphics{}, \bibliography{} did not take into account that the whole project was meant to be moved into an "Old/" subfolder in the future (and suppose the same for the "New/main.tex" file). Is there a simple way to **change the paths** of all these commands via the latexmkrc file **before calling latexpand**?.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Once you've run latexpand, the `\input` directives are already removed from your `old.tex` and `new.tex` files, so there shouldn't be any issue. Can you clarify the problem you're getting?

Comment: Also, if your problem is that `new.tex` is not in the `New` directory, why not just `latexpand New/main.tex > New/expanded.tex` ?

Comment: Hmmm, the problem is that I'm copying the entire project into the New/ and Old/ folders and latexpand won't replace the paths correctly if I don't change all my \input{...} calls to \input{New/...} and \input{Old/...} (manually). This is tedious and I'd like to know if there's a way to automate it.

Comment: I've tried redefining "\input" globally (to include New/ or Old/ to the paths) but... when I do this, latexdiff doesn't color the contents of my inputs after latexpanding them. On the contrary, when I change my \input calls manually, latexdiff works just perfectly. What is most intriguing is that, in both cases, the latexpanded pdfs are fine.